# Easy prevention of unintended lines after crop in Photoshop cs6?

Tags: photoshop, noise, cropping

After cropping and saving for web as jpeg (maximum, optimized, convert to sRGB selected) there are unintended 1px gray lines around the border of my images that have a white background. I've read that I can flatten to remove these, but do I flatten first then crop, or crop and then flatten?

I imagine it's the former. Are there other ways to prevent these lines?

Comment: Can you post an example that I can check? If it's in the image, I don't think flattening is going to remove it. My first thought was that when you're cropping, you're crop area is set just 1px outside of the original on all sides. What happens if you use Image > Canvas Size, set the scale to Pixels, then reduce by 2px both vertical and horizontal, ensuring the anchor remains in the centre?

Comment: Doing a rectangular marquee select with antialiasing and using "crop to selection" will also do that. There's a crop tool that doesn't; it's easier than making sure that the antialiasing and feather are set the way you need them every time you do a selection.